# Error while running selenium WebDriver jar on Linux (Working fine on Windows)

Tags: java, linux, selenium, jar

I am running a .jar file of selenium Webdriver java code on Linux server but getting below error:

> A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver

ALL the dependency .jar are added in final .jar file
and I am using command :
**java -jar fileName.jar**

Comment: I am using selenium 3.4.0 version, **org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver ** is imported in java code and all the jars under lib folder are added to classpath in Linux

Answer (score 0):

It looks like its a clear case of missing selenium libraries in your uber jar.

The best way to check if your jar `fileName.jar` contains the `WebDriver` classes is to run something like this :

Here's an example

```
jar tvf selenium-server-standalone-3.5.0.jar | grep org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.class
1305 Fri Feb 01 00:00:00 IST 1985 org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.class
```

Depending on your uber jar building mechanism, you would need to ensure that you add up the webdriver jars into your uber jar.